# Is there a workaround for using espresso with Lollipop (Android 21)?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Attempting to run a test with UI-related code using espresso (i.e. `GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner`) on a Nexus 7 with Lollipop gives the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This message cannot be recycled because it is still in use.
at android.os.Message.recycle(Message.java:279)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:468)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopMainThreadUntilIdle(UiControllerImpl.java:337)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:94)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)`

This has apparently been a [known issue for several months](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=84) but since there have been [no commits since January 8](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/list), it is unknown whether there will be an official fix.

There is a comment in the discussion thread that states

> Just removing  message.recycle(); seems to fix it...

Is this a valid workaround? If not, what would the correct fix be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: Use Espresso 2.0 for Lollipop support 
https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

<s>Yes, if you remove "message.recycle(); " and rebuild it will solve that problem.</s>

The Espresso team announced at GTAC that the next release of Espresso will be in AOSP before too long. See video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHcmsK9jfGU

( I was the original poster of that issue you referenced )

UPDATE:

```
// you will want to keep it for older API versions
if ( SDK_INT < 21 ){
    message.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad you were able to revisit the answer since your original post on July 1.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link to that video as well.

Comment: Hey I'm stuck, and your answer seems solving my problem.
From which class I need to remove recycle() method?